# Nomenclature and Index does not show up in a standard thesis template

Tags: indexing, nomenclature, overleaf

Well, hello folks,

I am writing a thesis in a specific latex template that my department created.
I simply imported the zip file of the template into an overleaf project, and compiled. However the *nomenclature* and the *index* do not show up at all in the pdf.

my main .tex file (mscThesis.tex) that pdfLatex compiles, consists of the following relevant parts:

```
% Finalize the thesis data
\setThesisInfo
% ...
% some other code
% ...
\begin{document}
% ...
% Some example code here
% ... at some point:
% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\printbib{MyBib}
%
\include{glossary}
%
% Index
\cleardoublepage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

In the file `glossary.tex` we find

```
% Glossary
\chapter{Glossary} %
%
\printacronyms
\begin{acronym}[\hspace{0.8in}] % 0.8in is also used by the nomenclature
    \acro{3mE}[3\textlarger{m}E]{Mechanical, Maritime and Materials Engineering}%
    \acro{AMS}{American Mathematical Society}%
    \acro{DCSC}{Delft Center for Systems and Control}%
    \acro{TU}[TU D\textlarger{elft}]{Delft University of Technology}%
\end{acronym}%
%
%
% Nomenclature
\printnomencl%
```

The command `setThesisInfo` is defined in `mscThesis.cls`:

```
\newcommand{\setThesisInfo}{%
  \makenomenclature
  \makeindex
  \hypersetup{pdftitle=Masters Thesis: \msctitle,
            pdfauthor=\mscname,
            pdfsubject=\mscsubtitle,
            pdfkeywords=\msckeywords}
}
```

Other relevant definitions in `mscThesis.cls` are:

```
\RequirePackage{nomencl}                                % cool nomenclature listing
\RequirePackage{makeidx}  
% ...
% some other definition code
% ... then at some point this:
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-0.5\parsep}
\newcommand{\abbrev}[2]%
           {#2 (#1)\nomenclature[a ]{#1}{\MakeUppercase#2}}
\newcommand{\lsymb}[2]%
           {#1\nomenclature[c ]{#1}{\MakeUppercase#2}}
\newcommand{\gsymb}[2]%
           {#1\nomenclature[b ]{#1}{\MakeUppercase#2}}
\newcommand{\subs}[2]%
           {\nomenclature[d ]{$ _{#1} $}{\MakeUppercase#2}}
\newcommand{\supers}[2]%
           {\nomenclature[e ]{$ ^{#1} $}{\MakeUppercase#2}}
\newcommand{\others}[2]%
           {\nomenclature[f ]{#1}{\MakeUppercase#2}}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
    \medskip\item[\large\textbf{\textsf{Abbreviations}}]\medskip}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{%    
%      \medskip\item[\large\textbf{\textsf{Latin Symbols}}]\medskip}{%
            \medskip}{%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{%
%        \medskip\item[\large\textbf{\textsf{Greek Symbols}}]\medskip}{%
                \medskip}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{D}}{%
%          \medskip\item[\large\textbf{\textsf{Subscripts}}]\medskip}{%
                    \medskip}{%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{E}}{%
%            \medskip\item[\large\textbf{\textsf{Superscripts}}]\medskip}{%
            \medskip}{%
              \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{F}}{%
%                \medskip\item[\large\textbf{\textsf{Other}}]\medskip}
                \medskip}{%
                }%
   }}}}}}
\newcommand{\printnomencl}{%
  \phantomsection % Added by Martijn van de Giessen
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}\nomname}
%  \markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}
  \printnomenclature[0.8in]
}
```

In the compiled `mscThesis.tex` file, we do have some examples of indexed content and of nomenclature examples, so it is probably not that there are simply not any examples to output. 
E.g. :

```
\section{About the Nomenclature}

When you use symbols in your thesis -- as you probably will -- you can put them into the nomenclature listing (List of Symbols) at the back of your thesis. \tabref{tab:nomencl} shows the \LaTeX\ commands you need.\index{nomenclature}

\begin{table}%
    \centering
    \caption{Nomenclature codes}
    \label{tab:nomencl}
    \begin{tabular}{llcl}
        \toprule
        Code & Usage & Example\\
        \midrule
        \verb"\gsymb{}" & Greek symbols & \gsymb{$\gamma$}{Path Angle}\\
        \verb"\lsymb{}" & Letter symbols & \lsymb{$H(s)$}{Transfer function}\\
        \verb"\supers{}" & Superscript symbols & \supers{max}{Maximum} &\emph{only printed in the List of Symbols} \\
        \verb"\subs{}" & Subscript symbols & \subs{min}{Minimum} &\emph{only printed in the List of Symbols}\\
        \verb"\others{}" & Other symbols & \others{[kts]}{Knots} \others{$^{\circ}$, [deg]}{Degrees} &\emph{only printed in the List of Symbols}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Finally, maybe it has to do with the .ist files: `myindex.ist` and `mynomencl.ist`. I notice these files are nowere specifically mentioned in the preamble or class definition, but they are part of the project. Is that maybe it?
If not, **any suggestions on how to make the nomenclature and index appear in the Pdf, while making use of the given template?**

Let me know if things need to be cleared up, or any edit requests. I'm happy to modify this question.

---

If necessary, you can download the full .zip file of the template from [here.](http://www.dcsc.tudelft.nl/Education/MScTemplateLatex_new.zip)

**EDIT**
As per a good suggestion from the comments:
I will post the read-only link of the overleaf project [here.](https://www.overleaf.com/read/nkryckffgrcf)

Comment: Uploading files from the .zip to Overleaf does work for me, i.e. the Index, the Glossary (Acronyms and Symbols) all appear in the output: https://www.overleaf.com/read/bmgdjbfpjkvt
 If you're still having an issue with your project on Overleaf, you can post its read-only URL here, or you can email support@overleaf.com with your project ID, and someone will help have a look.

Comment: Good point! I have edited my question and posted the read-only link. I can see that it works on the link you posted. That is weird. Did you change any options ?

Comment: Thanks for the read-only link; now I see the issue: Nomenclatures, glossaries, indices etc will only work in an Overleaf project if the main file is on the _top level_ and not in a subfolder—and this is the difference between your project and mine!

Comment: Wow you're right! It works now! thanks for the help. Do you want to make an answer out of your comment? If not I can do it as well. Simply so that others might benefit from it if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.

On Overleaf V2, `makeindex` (also `makeglossaries`) will only run correctly if the project's main file is placed in the project's top level, instead of inside a subfolder. Incidentally this is also a pre-requisite for the word count and SyncTeX to function in Overleaf V2 projects.